# android: html in textview with link clickable

Tags: android, html, textview

I use an a-htmltag in my `TextView`, but when i tap on it nothing happens.

How can I make it open the web browser with the url?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

**Try this**

```
txtTest.setText( Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>"));
txtTest.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Remember :** don't use android:autoLink="web" attribute with it. because it causes LinkMovementMethod doesn't work.

**Update for SDK 24+**
The function `Html.fromHtml` deprecated on `Android N` (SDK v24), so turn to use this method:

```
    String html = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>";
    Spanned result = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    txtTest.setText(result);
    txtTest.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Here are the list of flags:**

```
FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
```

**Update 2**
with `android.text.util.Linkify`, it's more easier now to make a clickable TextView:

```
TextView textView =...
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: Remember don't use android:autoLink="web" attribute. because it causes LinkMovementMethod doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain? How it works?

Comment: this is great, maybe a little explanation of the classes used would be nice. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for this. I've several links that I'd like to embed in a string of text and this works.

Comment: It works really well, even if the link is part of a more complex html text. You saved me a lot of time, thanks! +1

Comment: You can now also use `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)` as a convenience, instead of checking API version yourself

Answer (score 16):

You can do it this way;

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
String text = "Visit my developer.android.com";
mTextView.setText(text);
// pattern we want to match and turn into a clickable link
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("developer.android.com");
// prefix our pattern with http://
Linkify.addLinks(mTextView, pattern, "http://")
```

Comment: link in the answer is dead