# Handle VIEW action without scheme

Tags: android

Faced to a next issue:

My app receives some HTML formatted data from server. I display it inside a TextView.The text for sure can contain links (`<a href="http://www.google.com">`). Making links clickable is not a problem following, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable) clarifications.

```
mTvContent = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);
mTvContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Code above works perfectly until server sends me a link without HTML scheme identifier , for example `<a href="www.google.com">`

Clicking on such link will cause the obvious ecxeption:

> E/AndroidRuntime(10646): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No
> Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action .VIEW
> dat=www.google.com (has extras) } E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1683)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1554)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3409)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3580)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3548)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7770)
> E/AndroidRuntime(10646):        at
> android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7198)

Actually I can parse received HTML code and "repair" links, but I don't like this idea.
Could somebody suggest any possible solution how to handle "broken" links?