# Android: web link in App Widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Hi and thank you for your consideration.

I am trying to put a clickable web link inside a TextView in an App Widget.

```
        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fbzcy7NxBuE");
        updateViews.setInt(R.id.text, "setAutoLinkMask", Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

But I am getting mixed results:

- either I am not able to click on the link,
- or I get "Unfortunately, Launcher has stopped" (using Nexus 7)

**Please is it possible to put clickable web links in App Widgets??**

thanks

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable][2]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697084/handle-textview-link-click-in-my-android-app
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable

I hope it helped..

Comment: @BeginnerAndroid thank you, it did not help, I think the problem is specific of App Widgets. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I put a PendingIntent on the text.