# Android TextView Clickable on <a href/> tag and link to browser

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

Surely, I knew that this question will duplicate of other questions. I have tried research about this; However it's not correct even I follow than.

```
var html_first = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://www.google.com'> here </a> ", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    } else {
        Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://www.google.com'> here </a>" )
    }
 text_view.setText(html_first)
```

I try to set html to text at Above code. 
as I searched, they suggest me to add

```
text_view.isClickable = true    
text_view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

And also I removed

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Cuz it's surely that **autoLink** is not fix with this condition.

with permission, I already added with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any idea with this cuz I cannot click **here** and link to browser
Thank in advance. :D

**ANSWER UPDATED**

with this, I solved it by move html to use string.xml. so we no need html more.

```
text_view.setText(R.string.google)
text_view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

and inside strings.xml

```
<string name = "google"> go to <a href = "www.google.com" >google</a></string>
```

I hope this help you. :D

Answer (score 1):

[have a look this guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722574/3502024)

Though its java version but should work. Try to use the FLAG **Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY** instead of **Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT** .