# Text view html link not clickable

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to make some text contain a hyper link for the view.

The html

```
<p>Random text with a <a href='https://myinsights-test.myunitron.com/' target='_blank' rel='noopener'>Link</a></p>
```

The text view

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="@{Html.fromHtml(viewModel.htmlBody)}"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

the html is coming from a remote server so I don't have full control, although we've agreed to keep it this level of simple.

Comment: Check out solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can make link clickable for Android Part
Pass you data in HTML.fromHtml as I have passed

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">This is a link</a>"));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```