# How to show links in Html.fromHtml if they were in <p> element?

Tags: android

**Greetings!**

I want to format this HTML into textview:

```
<p><a href="https://developerfromjokela.com">Attachment</a></p>
```

I expect `<a>` element to be like this:

[image: Screenshot with expected result]

What I get this instead:

[image: Screenshot with problem]

I think problem happens, because:

- Html class can't get links from element's child

Here is my code:

```
if (message.getContentHtml().split("<p>").length > 2)
                messageText.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(message.getContentHtml(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE));
            else
                messageText.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(message.getContentHtml(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING).toString().trim());
```

There is this trim because HTML.fromHtml is generating some spaces, and if there is only one row, it can be trimmed to look nice in UI. I tried removing it, but still link is not shown.

Thanks for helping
Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: html in textview with link clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438713/android-html-in-textview-with-link-clickable)

Comment: Look at the pictures, do you understand that link is not showing as a link in textview, because there is a <p>? Please remove that duplicate, because you didn't understand my question.

Comment: If you give the value from string file in your layout and add this `textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` in your java code will just work fine.

Comment: Problem is that the HTML string comes from the server, it's not static string, and that method is already added.

Comment: But even dynamic they have the answer [in the same link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722574/900128)

Comment: But my problem is not that my link is not clickable, but Html class doesn't recognize it as a <a> element if it's inside a <p> element. Do you understand? First image is the same link without being inside <p>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192844/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-developer-from-jokela).